# Is there any way to run Javac turning off code generation?

Tags: java, javac

I'd be interested to know whether it's possible to run javac or an equivalent tool to just analyze the given Java source code without actually generating any code.

The usefulness would lie in being able to verify whether my Java code is correct without having to generate any .class output files.

Thanks

Comment: Analyze how? And code generation = generation of `.class` files?

Comment: I want to know if there are any build errors / warnings.

Comment: And I'd be interest to know what's the problem with the question, as it seems a perfectly valid SO question..

Comment: The problem with the question is that it is very brief and it takes at least a second thought to understand what you mean. Make it easy for the reader or they are quicker at downvoting / closing the question than figuring out what you are asking.

Comment: Having this question marked as "off-topic" is a complete joke on the nature of the site.

Comment: @devouredelysium While I agree (vote to reopen), could you explain why having a .class generated is a bad thing? Even if you don't want to use it

Comment: If you have no use for the output files (i.e., you are a server that is only concerned in verified that the .java files "compile"), compiling the .class files will only waste time.

Comment: @devouredelysium This is not something I ever worried much about before.  Could you provide an estimate of how much time would be wasted on your zillion file build.  I would guess that you want this for something like a pre-commit hook that rejects commits that will not compile, but has no need of the generated class files.

Comment: @emory: as you may imagine, to make that kind of benchmark I'd need to actually be able to not generate the .class files. And to do that, I created this same thread..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is.  I have never tried it, so I can not verify that this actually works, but ...

`javac -proc:only`

means that only annotation processing is done, without any subsequent compilation.

If that did not work, what is wrong with just using

`javac -d /dev/null`

Comment: "If that did not work, what is wrong with just using javac -d /dev/null". I'm a windows user, but I'd guess that would make my zillion files builds take a lot more time than just bypassing the whole code-generation phase.

Comment: If time is what you are concerned with, I think you should time javac -proc:only versus regular javac.  A naive implementation of -proc:only would be to auto delete the generated class files.

Comment: I'll be doing that kind of tests soon enough.

Comment: Both methods are not working with jdk1.8. I get: `warning: Annotation processing without compilation requested but no processors were found.`  and `javac: not a directory: /dev/null`

Comment: @eadmaster wrt (1) I think that warning means you have not provided any processors.  Do you get the warning when you do not try to turn off code generation.  wrt (2) I admit I have never tried that approach and it is possible that it does not work.

Comment: Linux user here, in fact, `javac -d /dev/null` does not work: `javac: not a directory: /dev/null`

Answer (score 4):

You may be interested in the [Java Tools API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html). This API gives you programmatic control over the [Java compiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) and you can pretty much write a program to read and analyze a Java program. The API docs give an example of compiling a list of compiler error messages.